# Call a new function after JQuery Autocomplete populates input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am having the following issue. I have a form where a user selects an item with JQuery autocomplete. After the user selects the item, the function auto-populates these input fields with the values returned from Ajax call: `itemDescriptionSales`, `itemQuantity`, `itemPrice`, `itemPriceTotal`. After all these fields are populated, I need to call a new function `recalcuateTotal` to recalculate a price total based on the values inside the input fields. The problem is that the the function `recalculateTotal` is called before all input field are populated with a value. I tried to call the function with the following code but obviously it doesn't work.

```
$( ".itemCode" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function(  ) {

    recalculateTotal();
} );
```

I also tried to implement `setTimeout(recalculateTotal, 1000)` that would delay the function call. I believe that that's not the right approach though. Would anybody have any suggestions ho to solve this? I have the following code for the autocomplete function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$( function() {

$( ".itemCode" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: "items-search.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    } );
  },
  minLength: 3,
  select: function( event, ui ) {

      $(this).parent().siblings().children(".itemDescriptionSales").val(ui.item.itemDescriptionSales);
      $(this).parent().siblings().children(".itemQuantity").val(ui.item.itemQuantity);
      $(this).parent().siblings().children(".itemPrice").val(ui.item.itemPrice);
      $(this).parent().siblings().children(".itemPriceTotal").val((ui.item.itemPrice)*(ui.item.itemQuantity));

    },

} );

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call it in the `select` callback after you populate the new values

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  var $inputs = $(this).parent().siblings().children()
  $inputs.filter(".itemDescriptionSales").val(ui.item.itemDescriptionSales);
  $inputs.filter(".itemQuantity").val(ui.item.itemQuantity);
  $inputs.filter(".itemPrice").val(ui.item.itemPrice);
  $inputs.filter(".itemPriceTotal").val((ui.item.itemPrice) * (ui.item.itemQuantity));
  // values are updated so can calculate now
  recalculateTotal();

}
```